# How did the author Daniel copy Babylonian literature?

Tags: history, prophecy, apologetics, daniel

This is an apologetics question involving history and archeology to which I’m looking for a christian’s answer.

Below is a quote from theologian Joyce G. Baldwin on her essay (pg.97) regarding the date for the book of Daniel in light of what are known as the “Akkadian Prophecies”.

Here is a link to the full essay: https://legacy.tyndalehouse.com/tynbul/Library/TynBull_1979_30_04_Baldwin_LiteraryDaniel.pdf

Please notice the bits in bold where Baldwin quotes “Professor Lambert” (assuming it’s archeologist Wilfred G. Lambert). He’s basically saying it’s very unlikely for a second century Judean to have direct knowledge of such cuneiform texts and thus the texts HAD to have been translated and dispersed into another language understandable to the supposed Maccabean author of Daniel 8-11.

I’ve done some informal research and found that so far there isn’t any examples of Babylonian cuneiform script being translated into Hellenistic languages such as Greek, though there are transcriptions.

My question is: How reasonable is Professor Lambert’s conclusion? How possible would it have been for Babylonian cuneiform tablets to have been translated in a common language and passed hands until it reached the author of Daniel in the mid second century BC?

> resemblance [between the Akkadian Prophecies and Daniel] proves to be a considerable embarrassment to those who accept a second century date for the writing of Daniel. How did a Jewish author in Palestine at that time become so fully acquainted with Babylonian texts? Professor Lambert in his 1977 lecture grappled with this question at some length, aware that **'the formidable cuneiform script would prevent any first hand acquaintance'**./43/ Maybe there was an antecedent author, or a Greek source, Lambert says, 'In Greek I have not discovered any fully comparable texts antedating Daniel. **It remains, then, to show that this Babylonian genre could have been disseminated in a form intelligible, to Jews.**'

Comment: I think it would be better to ask this at [hermeneutics.se]. If you make clear in your question that you're looking for evidence concerning the authorship and dating and the specific claims that Daniel 11 was borrowed(?) from extra-Biblical texts then it should be on-topic there.

Comment: I have already posted this question in Hermeneutics and they said to bring it here. I’m looking for something a bit more specific than simply evidence of the dating and authorship of Daniel. It involves history and archeology - something which isn’t to do with hermeneutics but is to do with Christian Apologetics

Comment: The title of your question should be a question (i.e. a sentence ending in a question mark), please edit don't rollback fairly obvious edits that improve your post made by moderators or experienced users, this is a team effort.

Comment: The last title edit seemed bias to me. I’ve changed the title but in any case I’m not getting any answers and I’d doubt a change in the title will make much difference

Comment: @user it's all a game of perceptions, trust me!  If your question is closed it's not gonna get any answers.  But you might have to wait, for instance, I just got a first answer to a question I wrote in 2016!

Comment: I’m pretty sure in 6 years time I’d have already found a satisfactory answer to this question on another website like quora or Reddit etc.